# nodemon clean exit - waiting for changes before restart problem

Tags: node.js, express

I have index.html, style.css, and script.js files in the same root directory that I want to appear on a port. This is why I'm using the app.use code below. But my server isn't running.

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT}`));
```